# Dynamic Cache Prefix For Multi Tenancy Database

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am working in a multi tenancy Lumen project (v8.3.4) and using this [mostafamaklad/laravel-permission-mongodb](https://github.com/mostafamaklad/laravel-permission-mongodb) (v3.1.0)package for user's role-permission handling.

The problem I am facing is roles and permissions for each tenant is cached by the package using the same cache key. So if the tenants are switched then the roles and permission are served form the cache and no tenant based DB call is made. Hence the package always return error.

I am looking for a way to prefix cache for each tenant separately. and I have tried some methods but didn't succeed in making it work.

Some of the methods I tried so far are:

1. Put a middleware to prefix cache key using tenant id => It didn't work cause the package service provider registers the models and get the cache even before middleware executed.
2. Register the package service provider inside a middleware => It didn't work cause the package probably building using the default configurations
3. When the cache prefix is set in `ServiceProviders` then the package does not recognize the values and using the default ones I guess

Hope the issue is clear and let me know if any clarification needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that providers in the `Illuminate` namespace will be loaded first. You can resolve this with the following hack:

1. Create a service provider (let's call it `CachePrefixServiceProvider`) in `app\Providers` to prefix the cache with the tenant id. Change the namespace to something like `Illuminate\MyProject`. The service provider will look something like this:

```
namespace Illuminate\MyProject;

/**
 * Class CachePrefixServiceProvider (incorrect namespace, hack to be loaded first)
 *
 * @package Illuminate\MyProject\CachePrefixServiceProvider
 */
class CachePrefixServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // Take the tenant id from the header or somewhere else   
        $tenantId = request()->header('tenant-id');

        // In case of file cache    
        if (config('cache.default') === 'file') {
            config(
                 ['cache.stores.file.path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data/' . $tenantId)]
            );

            return;
        }

        // Will work in case of Redis / Memcached
        config(['cache.prefix' => $tenantId . '_cache']);
    }
}
```

Of course you can change the prefix to your needs.

2. You will get an error that autoloading will fail because the provider doesn't match PSR standards. You can resolve this by adding the class to the autoload field in your composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Providers/CachePrefixServiceProvider.php"
    ],
...
}
```

Don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload`.

3. Add the provider to the providers in `config/app.php`:

```
Illuminate\MyProject\CachePrefixServiceProvider::class,
```

Any other solutions that don't involve this hack will be appreciated.

Comment: I have followed the exact steps you provided but It throws an error, `Class 'Illuminate\\VM\\CachePrefixServiceProvider`.

Comment: What is the exact error @iamab.in?

Comment: `namespace Illuminate\VM` is my service provider namespace.  When I add `$app->register(Illuminate\VM\CachePrefixServiceProvider::class);` In my lumen app's bootstrap/app.php file. then the following error throws. `Class 'Illuminate\VM\CachePrefixServiceProvider' not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class 'Illuminate\\VM\\CachePrefixServiceProvider' not found at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vm\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Application.php:223)` .

Comment: Did you add it to composer.json and did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to run `composer dump-autoload`. Now the error is not there. Let me check the results

Comment: `dd(config('cache'));`  inside a middleware returns the default cache configuration. the prefix set in provider isn't loaded

Comment: Are you sure the `$tenantId` value is set correctly in the provider, and isn't `null`?

Comment: yes. `$tenantId` is not empty. If I `dd(config('cache'))` inside the service provider after setting config, it shows the `array:1 ["prefix" => "9892cf8b-cc6e-4e27-85e1e12bcfcd07fd_cache"]`. Only my custom set config values is set no other values were loaded. And the package isn't getting the config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252617/discussion-between-piscator-and-iamab-in).